# Before/after parametrized test in JUnit5

Tags: testing, junit5

I haven't been able to find a way how to run a custom method before and after a parametrized test.

Do you know if there is a way for JUnit 5?

Something like I saw for JUnit 4:
https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.BeforeParam.html

Edit:
I would need something like this:

```
class BeforeAfterParameterizedTest {

    @BeforeParametrizedTest("test")
    void setUp() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method before parameterized test");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"foo", "bar"})
    void test(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @AfterParametrizedTest("test")
    void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method after parameterized test");
    }

}
```

With output:

```
invoke custom method before parameterized test 
foo
bar
invoke custom method after parameterized test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifecycle methods are also executed for parameterized tests, so you can invoke your custom method(s) in `@BeforeEach`/`@AfterEach`:

```java
class BeforeAfterParameterizedTest {

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method before each parameterized test");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"foo", "bar"})
    void test(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method after each parameterized test");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
invoke custom method before each parameterized test
foo
invoke custom method after each parameterized test
invoke custom method before each parameterized test
bar
invoke custom method after each parameterized test
```

**EDIT:** Given [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320108/before-after-parametrized-test-in-junit5/75597449#comment133381170_75597449):

> […] I need my custom method to be executed only once before all and after all runs of the parametrized test, so from your example I would need output: invoke custom method before all parameterized test foo bar invoke custom method after all parameterized test

You can use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` instead:

```java
class BeforeAfterParameterizedTest {

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpOnce() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method before all parameterized tests");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"foo", "bar"})
    void test(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownOnce() {
        System.out.println("invoke custom method after all parameterized tests");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
invoke custom method before all parameterized tests
foo
bar
invoke custom method after all parameterized tests
```

If your test class contains other tests you don't want the custom method to be executed for, you can wrap the parameterized test and the setup / teardown methods in a [nested test](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested). (Note that you need Java 16+ to have static methods in inner classes, see [JEP 395](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).)

Comment: Thank you, I may not explain it properly, I need my custom method to be executed only once before all and after all runs of the parametrized test, so from your example I would need output:

invoke custom method before all parameterized test
foo
bar
invoke custom method after all parameterized test

Comment: @vonda I have edited the answer accordingly. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you. I am accepting your answer. Although I hoped there was a less wordy solution (no nested classes).

Comment: @vonda alternatively, you could write a custom [extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions), which implements [`BeforeAllCallback`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeAllCallback.html) and [`AfterAllCallback`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterAllCallback.html). (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75608953/3429133) for a basic example.) This way you can avoid `@Nested` and put the ceremony elsewhere.