# Does JUnit 5 have anything like Cucumber's tagged hooks?

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber, junit5

Is there any way to annotate single test with hooks in JUnit5 like in Cucumber?

For example in cucumber it's possible to write hook like

```
@Before("@SomeTest")
public void beforeSomeTest(){
}
```

And then if we tag test with @SomeTest annotation then hook will run before test.

Is there any way to do this in JUnit5?

Comment: The extension API is mostly about exactly that. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@johanneslink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602216/does-junit-5-have-anything-like-cucumbers-tagged-hooks#comment133392501_75602216), [extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) are the JUnit Jupiter way of doing stuff like that:

```java
class MyTest {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
    @interface MyAnnotation {

    }

    static class MyExtension implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback {

        @Override
        public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) {
            System.out.println("extension");
        }

    }

    @Test
    @MyAnnotation
    void testWithExtension() {
        System.out.println("test with extension");
    }

    @Test
    void testWithoutExtension() {
        System.out.println("test without extension");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
extension
test with extension
test without extension
```